# how to merge an image button into an imageview in an android app

Tags: android, button, web, imageview

i am working on an app for both ios and android. In a particular activity i am showing an imageview full of text. In that i am highlighting particular text with yellow color. When the user clicks over them it takes him to a webpage.

The particular text is been at the middle and at the end of the image. For this in my ios app
i got the image with a blank space in between and in those blank spaces i have added an image button, so that when the user clicks it opens the web page. In ios the resolution of the app is to be a fixed one.

i have one more problem here. If the user changes his language to be german or korean currently i am changing the images  with the corresponding text in my ios app, but here i have to create text in those language. I felt it to be very hard, tats why i am trying to use image itself....

But how can i do this in my android app. Can anyone help me in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not need to show an image in the ImageView, I suggest to use a TextView instead. You can put all your text in the TextView, and with the android:autoLink="all" attribute, all links to webpages, phonenumbers, maps and email will be highlighted! Also, you can set a background image or background gradient

Here's an example for your main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TextView 
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:background="@drawable/gradient" 
        android:autoLink="all"
        android:text="Email: public@nytimes.com \n
            Phone: 212-556-7652 \n
            Address: 620 Eighth avenue New York, NY 10018 \n 
            Website: http://www.nytimes.com " >
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here's the code for the background gradient (which you should put in the drawables folder):

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
        <gradient
        android:startColor="#ff305385"
        android:endColor="#ff3A6195"
        android:angle="90" />
</shape>
```

Comment: sorry.... already i am using what you have said above but i have one more problem here. If the user changes his language to be german or korean currently i am changing the images in my ios app, but here i have to create text in those language. I felt it to be very hard, thats why i am trying to use image itself....

Comment: You could also use a relative layout, and then position the ImageViews relative to each other. If positioned correct, the images will adjust their position correctly, in case of changes. Also, you can set onClickListeners to the images that need to be clicked...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question completely, but it sounds like you can do it using `SpannableString` built of text-image-text and set to a `TextView`